# Python json schema formatchecker not validating valid datetime strings

Tags: python, datetime, jsonschema

I'm using a valid datetime string to validate in my data using JSON schema formatchecker but it didn't validate this valid date-time format and fails with the following error:

```
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: '2013-09-16T15:40:16.21211' is not a 'date-time'
```

My Code:

```
import jsonschema
import json 

data = {"timestamp": "2013-09-16T15:40:16.21211"}

schema ="""{
    "type":"object",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
    "id": "http://jsonschema.net",
    "required":true,
    "properties":{
        "timestamp": { 
            "format" :"date-time",
            "type":"string",
            "required" :false
        }
     }}"""

jsonschema.validate(data,json.loads(schema),format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker())
```

Answer (score 2):

The `date-time` validator [requires the format](https://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.7.3.1) ("Date and time format names are derived from RFC 3339, section 5.6 ") to conform with that specified in [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339):

```
date-fullyear   = 4DIGIT
date-month      = 2DIGIT  ; 01-12
date-mday       = 2DIGIT  ; 01-28, 01-29, 01-30, 01-31 based on 
                          ; month/year
time-hour       = 2DIGIT  ; 00-23
time-minute     = 2DIGIT  ; 00-59
time-second     = 2DIGIT  ; 00-58, 00-59, 00-60 based on leap second
                          ; rules
time-secfrac    = "." 1*DIGIT
time-numoffset  = ("+" / "-") time-hour ":" time-minute
time-offset     = "Z" / time-numoffset

partial-time    = time-hour ":" time-minute ":" time-second
                 [time-secfrac]
full-date       = date-fullyear "-" date-month "-" date-mday
full-time       = partial-time time-offset

date-time       = full-date "T" full-time
```

The `full-time` part of the specification requires a `time-offset` to be specified, i.e. you have to add either `Z` after your datetime to denote that the time is in UTC, or you have to add the explicit offset (i.e. +0100 etc.).

Comment: Im using the format date-time in my schema which is full-date "T" full-time

Comment: I figured that out what you are saying, either adding Z at the end or explicit offset. Thanks